# Passing id from one table to another and getting a total union result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to obtain a result where id is passed from another table in this like expression.

Eg. `Id` is `B001,B002,B003...... B009` in `tblname2` and after passing all the id to `tblname1`, I want the combine result using `union`:

```
select * 
from tblname1 
where id like '%idfromtblname2%'
```

i.e

```
 select * 
 from tblname1 
 where id like '%B001%'

 union

 select * 
 from tblname1 
 where id like '%B002%'

 union 

 select * 
 from tblname1 
 where id like '%B003%'
```

Comment: Well, this is the problem that you have when you store values in delimited strings.  Fix your data structure and your query will be easier.  That is, you should have a table with one row per id, not an integer id represented in a string of ids in a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me emphasize the reasons why you have a bad design:

- A column should represent a single attribute of an entity, not a list of attributes.
- Your id represents a foreign key relationship between two entities.  You should declare foreign key relationships.
- SQL (in general) has poor string manipulation functions.
- Your queries cannot make use of indexing or partitions, and the optimizer is basically of no help.

You should have a junction table with one row per table1 id and table2 id.  That is the SQLish way of representing such data.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  You can use `like` in this case:

```
select t1.* 
from tblname1 t1
where ',' + @idfromtable2 + ',' like '%,' + t1.id + ',%';
```

or using a `join` directly:

```
select t1.* 
from tblname1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on ',' + t2.ids + ',' like '%,' + t1.id + ',%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me offer another version of this - Don't pass a parameter, just use `EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM tblname1 t 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblname2 s
             WHERE t.id LIKE '%' + s.<Col> + '%')
```

But, all depends on how you store your data .